# Does WordPress limit the length of slug names for Post Meta or Terms?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, post-meta, terms, slug

The WordPress Codex states the the Post Type Names and Taxonomy Names have a limit to the slug name.

- [Register Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) -- max. 20 characters, can not contain
  capital letters or spaces
- [Register Taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) -- The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in
  slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces) and not more
  than 32 characters long (database structure restriction).

However, the WordPress Codex doesn't state whether or not Post Meta or Terms have a limit to the slug name.

- [Add Post Meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) -- No slug limit?
- [Insert Term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) -- No slug limit?

Can this be confirmed? Is there no slug name limit for Post meta or Terms?

Comment: Please notice the newer naming conventions for the taxonomy name:

"The name of the taxonomy. Name should only contain lowercase letters and the underscore character, and not be more than 32 characters long (database structure restriction)."

see:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `meta_key` field for the `wp_postmeta` table is set as `varchar` type entries with a length of 255 characters. Seems pretty lengthy. It's `meta_value` partner parameter is set as `longtext` type.

As for the term length, both name and slug are set as `varchar` with a length of 200 characters each in the `wp_terms` table.